# shスクリプトからバイナリファイルを作るにはどうすればよいか

Tags: bash, shellscript, sh

ちょっとしたバイナリファイルが必要なときは`echo -n -e`で作っていますが、もっと楽にできる方法をご存じないでしょうか。

既に存在するバイナリファイルの変更は、odの結果をgawkで`echo`形式に加工してbashに渡していますが、新規に作るときが悩ましいです。余裕があればプログラムを書いて作っていますが、もっと手軽にできる方法を探しています。

**バイナリファイルを作る元の表現形式**

- 内容はランダムでよい
- 値は指定したい(16進数だけでも可、できれば文字列、10進数、16進数の混在が指定できるとなお良い)

**実行環境**

WSLを含むUnix系の環境

Comment: 参考: 英語版での類似質問 - [generate a binary file from a text file in linux shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12550702)

Comment: シェルスクリプト内で16進数の文字列からバイナリファイルを作る感じでよいのでしょうか？ もしそうなら xxd コマンドを使うことが多い気がします。 echo -n "48656c6c6f0a" | xxd -r -p > hello.bin

Comment: cubickさん、コメントありがとうございます。英語が苦手なので類似質問を探すのが苦手です。こうして特定してもらえると翻訳ソフトで何とか理解できますので大変たすかります。

Comment: sa-yさん、コメントありがとうございます。よろしければ回答として投稿していただければ、私以外の人にも後々役にたつと思いますがいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 中身は適当でも良いのであれば `head -c100 /dev/random > random.bin` Linux であれば `/dev/urandom` も利用可能です。

Comment: metropolisさん、コメントありがとうございます。内容は何でもよい場合と指定したい場合があるので、質問に追記しました。

Comment: 2桁の16進数の並びであれば `echo 011affb0ab | grep -Eo '..' | xargs -n1 -I@ printf '\x@'` でしょうか。

Comment: metropolis さん、コメントありがとうございます。試してみました。よさそうですね、よろしければ回答として投稿していただけないでしょうか、後々皆さんの役にたつと思います。コメントは消えることがあるようですので、そうなると残念です。

Comment: 補足：コメントは「必要がなくなった」として削除票が集まったりすると削除されます（もし削除されたら困るコメントが削除されてしまっていたら、メタに投稿してくださると助かります）。それとは別に、コメントでの回答は[質問の自動削除に繋がる可能性がある](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2645/19110)ため、解決した後でも構わないので回答として投稿してくださると嬉しいです。また、[第三者がコミュニティwikiとして回答することもできます](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1812/19110)。今回のように回答化をお願いするコメントをして下さるのはとても助かります。ありがとうございます。

Comment: hidezzzさんの回答でバイナリファイルを作ることにしました。
参考にされる方が質問の内容だけで完結しないよう、「回答」に転記しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

シェルスクリプト内でperlを使うことに抵抗がないなら、packを使うと第1引数のテンプレート文字列で変換方法を指定しつつ柔軟にバイナリ化させることが出来ます。

```
$ perl -e 'print pack( "NVnvCa15", 0x12345678, 0x12345678, 0xabcd, 0xabcd, 9, "test string" )' | hexdump -C
00000000  12 34 56 78 78 56 34 12  ab cd cd ab 09 74 65 73  |.4VxxV4......tes|
00000010  74 20 73 74 72 69 6e 67  00 00 00 00              |t string....|
0000001c
```

Answer (score 2):

コメント欄で解決しているようですので、回答として転載しておきますね。

> 2桁の16進数の並びであれば `echo 011affb0ab | grep -Eo '..' | xargs -n1 -I@ printf '\x@'` でしょうか。 – [metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis)

**追加: sed 版**

```
$ printf $(echo 011affb0ab | sed -E 's/(..)/\\x\1/g') | od -tx1a
0000000  01  1a  ff  b0  ab
        soh sub del   0   +
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。参考にします。いろいろと応用が利きそうですね。

Comment: `xargs` の `-n1` は不要だし、ないほうが効率がいいですね。

Answer (score 0):

自己回答です。hidezzzさんの回答の方法を参考にしてでバイナリファイルを作ることにしました。どうもありがとうございました。

perlの演算が使えるので結構自由度が大きいです。

perlのpackに詳しくないので、perlの良さがアピールできていませんが、実行例も書いておきました。

【コード】
qqq.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while read x y
do
        printf "%s\n" 'print pack( "'${x}'", '${y}' );'
done | perl
```

【実行例】

```
./qqq.sh  | od -Ax -x --endian=big
l 0x1234
A3 ABC
l (8*9)
```

【実行結果】

```
000000 3412 0000 4142 4348 0000 0000
00000b
```